# Decrease number length by rounding in java

Tags: java

There's a functionality in my project that does a multiplication of 3 different big decimals.

Sometimes, the result could give some really large numbers like:

```
213215648783612154.334 
or
421342342342342344.123
```

The thing is: the column which keeps record of this value is defined like NUMBER(8,3). Is there a way to decrease the length of this number by doing some rounding operations? I really don't want to redefine the column because it's being used in other parts of the system.

Comment: What's about just take a smaller maximum in your random function?

Comment: When you create your answer BigDecimal you can give it a rounding scale.

Comment: I know that i can give a rounding scale, but can i give it so the length of my number decreases? From like (14,3) to (8,3)?

Comment: What value you wan to be stored for `421342342342342344.123`? Remember maximum allowed value is `99999.999`

Comment: How on earth do you want these numbers to fit in 8 digits, even with a lot of rounding ? The only rounding which can do that is something like `if (number>99999999) { number = 99999999; }`, but it's certainly not what you want.

Comment: Rounding or truncating?

Answer (score 3):

You have a basic design or logic flaw in your system.

If you have a database that expects values as `NUMBER(8,3)`, then it is saying "I have space for 8 digits, 3 of them are decimals". The largest value that can be stored in that column is `99999.999`.

You cannot store any larger value. Period.

So, what is the issue? Either:

1. your program logic is wrong, and the values it is calculating like `213215648783612154.334` are just plain broken.... or
2. your database implementation is badly designed because it should be able to store larger values than planned.

Which one you fix depends on your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: It is impossible to round in some meaningful way. Because max value is `99999.999`

You can try encode instead rounding. But all other code that work with this column MUST be aware of encoding.
For example you can use first 5 digits as mantissa and last 3 as exponent (and hide sign somewhere). But i want to look at faces of your colleagues if you try it.

Answer (score 0):

hmm sure you can just cut off some of the numbers even though it might give you some wrong data hehe.

```
String number= Mynumber.tostring(); //assuming mynumber is the object that stores the number
number= number.substring( (number.length()-(number.length()-9)) , number.length()); //adding 1 to 8 because of the '.'
System.out.pritnln(number);
```

input =

```
213215648783612154.334
```

output:

```
12154.334
```